# ASP.NET MVC Validation on Complex Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am having difficulty in validation a Form on a View.

I have a controller that does a `UpdateModel(object);` and therefore not sure how to build validation.

I have added `[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a contact name")]` for all properties that are mandatory.

How do I make it all work? Since my Controller is doing some complex stuff. Below is the Controller code:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PersistListing()
    {
        var listingView = new MaintainListingView();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["Listing.Guid"]))
        {
            var dbListing = _service.GetByGuid<Listing>(Guid.Parse(Request["Listing.Guid"]));

            if (dbListing != null)
            {
                listingView.Listing = dbListing;
            }
        }

        UpdateModel(listingView);    
        RebindTranslationsDictionary(listingView.Listing);
        listingView.Listing.CategoryId = _service.GetByGuid<ListingCategory>(listingView.SelectedListingCategoryGuid).Id;
        _service.PersistEntity(listingView.Listing);
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = listingView.Listing.Guid });

    }
```

When I uncomment the Required attributes on the base Model then I get an error when I try to to UpdateModel();

Can anyone see a quick fix to this?

**EDIT**: I am using  I am using `Html.TextBoxFor()` to create controls on the View.

Added TryUpdateModel but unsure how to redirect the user with populated error messages:

```
     if (TryUpdateModel(listingView))
        {

            RebindTranslationsDictionary(listingView.Listing);

            listingView.Listing.CategoryId =
                _service.GetByGuid<ListingCategory>(listingView.SelectedListingCategoryGuid).Id;


            _service.PersistEntity(listingView.Listing); //save the ting


            return RedirectToAction("Edit", new {id = listingView.Listing.Guid});
          }
```

Do I need an EditForModel tag in my View?

Comment: Can you show us your model? And what is the exact error you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `TryUpdateModel` instead of `UpdateModel` as it will not throw exceptions and allow you to know whether validation has failed or not:

```
if (!TryUpdateModel(listingView))
{
    // there were validation errors => redisplay the view 
    // so that the user can fix those errors
    return View(listingView);
}  

// at this stage you know that validation has passed 
// and you could process the model ...
```

Comment: But I want the error messages to show. I am using Html.TextBoxFor() to create the controls.

Comment: Then add a corresponding `Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SomeProperty)` helper. Or use `Html.ValidationSummary()` to display all error messages.

Comment: Ok... Because my View is strongly typed, and if the TryUpdateModel fails, how do I redirect the user to the same view with the Error messages turned ON?

Comment: You simply return the view and pass the view model to it: `return View(listingView);`. There's no such thing in ASP.NET MVC as `Error messages turned ON`. If you have placed ValidationMessageFor helpers inside this view and there are errors in the ModelState then these errors will be shown. And it is the TryUpdateModel method that is adding those error messages to the ModelState when performing the model binding from the request values.

Comment: I have added the ValidationMessageFor on a Telephone input control but it doesn't error messages don't show:  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Listing.TelephoneNumber)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Listing.TelephoneNumber)

Comment: [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide a Telephone Number")]
        public string TelephoneNumber { get; set; }

Comment: Do I need an EditForModel tag in my View?

Comment: Ummm, I'm doing the redirect but.. It's not populating the error messages

Comment: Of course that it's not populating the error messages if you are doing a redirect. The ModelState is valid only for the current request. Don't do a redirect if you want to display error messages but rebder the same view again. Do a redirect only if the form submission succeeds. This is also known as the Redirect-After-Post pattern.

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense.